# PITR based recovery failing due to difference in max_connections

Tags: postgresql, recovery

During PITR based recovery of a postgres instance, we are getting the following error -

```
'2023-06-21 23:52:52.232 PDT [24244] FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 150 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 500)'
```

Here are the steps we are following -

1. We took a snapshot of the data disk from a Postgres leader node(let’s call this as source instance).
2. Then, we modified the MAX_CONNECTIONS in the source instance to 500.
3. Due to the modification, the following wal_file entry gets generated -

```
rmgr: XLOG len (rec/tot): 54/54, tx: 0, lsn: 1/5E0000A0, prev 1/5E000028, desc: PARAMETER_CHANGE max_connections=500 max_worker_processes=8 max_wal_senders=10 max_prepared_xacts=0 max_locks_per_xact=64 wal_level=replica wal_log_hints=off track_commit_timestamp=off
```

4. Next, we did a PITR based recovery in another PG instance. During recovery, the config file used has MAX_CONNECTIONS value set to 150.
5. However, the recovery fails with the following error -

```
'2023-06-21 23:52:52.232 PDT [24244] FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 150 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 500)'
```

What are the probable solutions to fix this issue?
One of the approaches we tried was to set `‘hot_standby = off’` in postgresql.conf. By doing this, we are successfully able to restore the source’s content on the destination instance. However, is this the correct way to move forward?

We also read the postgres documentation for hot_standby - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hot-standby.html
It mentions -
“The settings of some parameters determine the size of shared memory for tracking transaction IDs, locks, and prepared transactions. These shared memory structures must be no smaller on a standby than on the primary in order to ensure that the standby does not run out of shared memory during recovery. For example, if the primary had used a prepared transaction but the standby had not allocated any shared memory for tracking prepared transactions, then recovery could not continue until the standby's configuration is changed.”

Does this mean that turning off hot_standby and then performing a recovery operation may lead to some unintended consequences? Do we always have to keep these parameter (‘max_connections’) values greater than equal to that of the source instance?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.